# identity MVC - invaild username or password after changing DB

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, identity, asp.net-identity

After i change the DB in the web.config, added connection strings like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;.....20140526021501;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="identityDB" connectionString="Server=....Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Of course "DefaultConnection" was always there i added the "identityDB" and i'm using it in :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("identityDB")
        {
        }
```

**Note:** the 'identityDB' are a SQL data base in Azure(cloud).

**The problem :**

When i register on the site the user is added to my database in the right table and all (all the fields are correct and everything is good).

But when i try to login with the username and password that i register i get the "Invaild username or password" message, i dont know why...

**I debug it** a little bit and i can see here:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }
```

The user return as a null in the "if" statement, what is the problem ? i cant undetstand why i can register but the login are failing...

Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

For some reason this line of code :

```
await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
```

got twisted beacuse as i understand "model.Email" is got mixed with "model.userName" and i don't have this property of "UserName" so i needed to change this line to other and still preform the same operation.

**The Solution:**

I will pass my code but first ill explain what i did :

i changed the problematic line with a couple of line that does the exact thing but in different order:

1. first check if the email appear in the DB.
2. if it does i will check the password, if it doesn't print the invalid user password message.
3. after it just continue as usual

**Here is my code:**

```
 // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            PasswordVerificationResult result = PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            //var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user != null)
            {
                result = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, model.Password);

                if (!(result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid name or password.");
                }
                else
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

As you can see i took the "problematic line" and comment it.

Hope it will help someone alone the way, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to update on Identity 2.0(but be careful). Also by this connection string it should work i guess. It is very odd that you can register user in db but you cant login with it. That might mean that when you register user it saves it to your db on azure and when you login it search your local db(that you deployed on azure with project). I would delete that local db and con string. But it makes no sense if you specified your constring right(check all con strings, clear browser cache do some phantom tricks...). Other might be that you entering wrong password. Set your password validation to allow you to enter eg. 111111 or some easy ones, to eliminate some mistakes in typing.

Comment: I'm working with Identity 2.0, i know its very odd...
The problem is that the user is null.
i will try what you suggested...

Comment: Can you make on your test env some field in ApplicationUser class and add password string to see password. Did you check maybe you specified some connection strings somewhere other in IdentityConfig or global asax

Comment: But all in all...this is pretty odd one

Comment: Try it...didnt work.
its a problem in this line :
 await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

i'm trying to get to the bottom of the "FindAsync" function

Comment: RandomBoy i figure it out and post my solution.
Thanks anyway